# How do I increase datetime ticks in ggplot (posixct)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am attempting to plot this dataset but increase the number of ticks on the x-axis.

```
        order_dates            Value
1     2022-08-28 00:00:10       80.9 
2     2022-08-28 00:16:40       81.6   
3     2022-08-28 00:33:28       81.2
4     2022-08-28 05:37:12       81.4
5     2022-08-28 08:52:24       89.0    
6     2022-08-28 09:50:28       100.6   
7     2022-08-28 12:30:08       84.9
```

`ggplot() +  geom_line(data=z, aes(x=order_dates, y=Value), lwd = 0.5, alpha = 0.6)`

This code results in x-ticks that are hourly, but I would like more ticks on the x-axis (say, every 30 minutes). order_dates is a Posixct class. Furthermore, I would like the x-axis to have both date and time (in the event I get different dates in the order_dates column). How can I achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: Try `scale_x_datetime(breaks = scales::date_breaks("30 mins"), date_labels = "%H:%M")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `scale_x_datetime`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() + 
  geom_line(data=z, aes(x=order_dates, y=as.numeric(Value)), lwd = 0.5, alpha = 0.6) +
  scale_x_datetime(date_breaks = "30 min", date_labels = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1))
```

Output:

[image]

Data:

```r
library(readr)

z <- read_delim("order_dates,Value
2022-08-28 00:00:10,80.9
2022-08-28 00:16:40,81.6 
2022-08-28 00:33:28,81.2
2022-08-28 05:37:12,81.4
2022-08-28 08:52:24,89.0
2022-08-28 09:50:28,100.6
2022-08-28 12:30:08,84.9")
```